# How can I show an AlertDialog inside a Progress Bar?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, progress-bar, android-alertdialog

> I don't know how I can show an AlertDialog, when the progress bar goes
>   for example to 22%.

I would like when the progress bar reaches 22%, to stop and show an Al*e*rtDialog window, showing some text and the default buttons, for example OK and Cancel. When you press OK the progress bar resumes and continues with the progress load. And so complete it until you reach 100% of the progress bar.

The problem is that I don't know how to stop the progress bar, for example at 22% and show the AlertDialog. So this is my doubt. How would be the right way to do it.

This is what I have done so far, and thank you in advance colleagues;)

**MainActivity**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ProgressBar progressBar4;
private int progressStatus4 = 0;
private Handler handler = new Handler();


    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                carga();
            }
        });
    }

    private void carga(){
        final Dialog dialogCorrect = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialogCorrect.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        if (dialogCorrect.getWindow() != null) {
            ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            dialogCorrect.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
        }
        dialogCorrect.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
        dialogCorrect.setCancelable(false);
        dialogCorrect.show();

        final TextView tv44 = dialogCorrect.findViewById(R.id.tv44);
        progressBar4 = dialogCorrect.findViewById(R.id.pb44);
        final TextView txt = dialogCorrect.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        txt.setText("Connect");

        if (progressStatus4 == 100) {
            progressStatus4 = 0; //Reset Values
        }

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (progressStatus4 < 100) {

                    progressStatus4 += 1;

                    try {
                         Thread.sleep(200);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                if(progressBar4.getProgress() >= 20 && progressBar4.getProgress() <= 41){
                                    txt.setText("Update"); 

                                }else if(progressBar4.getProgress() >= 41 && progressBar4.getProgress() <= 71){
                                    txt.setText("GET");

                                }else if(progressBar4.getProgress() >= 71 && progressBar4.getProgress() <= 99){
                                    txt.setText("WHAIT");

                                }else if(progressBar4.getProgress() >= 99 && progressBar4.getProgress() <= 100){
                                    dialogCorrect.dismiss(); //Close PopUp


                                }
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    // Update the progress bar
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            progressBar4.setProgress(progressStatus4);
                            progressBar4.setSecondaryProgress(progressStatus4 + 15);
                            // Show the progress on TextView
                            tv44.setText(progressStatus4 + "%");
                        }
                    });


                }
            }
        }).start(); // Start the operation
    }
}
```